# How to make API in GIMP?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, api, gimp

I was using Opencv to make APIs about image processing in visual studio 2010 and then use them in Android. now i started to use gimp and gegl library to do the same. but i dont find any reference about how to do.

i just want to know how to load and image using gimp and then manipulate the image and finally get an output. what are the functions? i saw some codes for gimp plugins. but the main() function is not present there. like in opencv i have something like this..

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
}
```

i tried to use the code from this link [how-to-use-gimp-drawable-set-pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964132/how-to-use-gimp-drawable-set-pixel). i am supposed to get a red pixel. but i cannot compile it in visual studio. i get this: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
i dont understand what i am missing.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I know GIMP is image editing software in a similar way as Photoshop is. Not a library like OpenCV. You can write plugins, which are exactly that...Plug ins. They hook into GIMP and as such don't have a regular main as you describe, but a similar named [macro](http://www.gimp.org/docs/plug-in/sect-essentials.html). You don't run them on their own.

Comment: you are right. actually i need to use the GEGL library for image processing in visual studio and then call the native code for android. i have seen this link: http://lightningismyname.blogspot.com/p/compiling-gimp.html#comment-form and it was really helpful. i followed all the steps. now i want to know how i can make simple API in visual studio using GEGL libraries and compile it. what changes i need to make in the "project properties" in the visual studio to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing is to go into the Gimp IRC-Channel. You can find more infos about it here:
http://wiki.gimp.org/index.php/Users:Beginner_Developer%27s_FAQ

Answer (score 0):

It may be that Gimp# can help you here.

This is a Plugin that provides an C# API for Gimp and can be found at [Sourceforge](http://gimp-sharp.sourceforge.net/).

This it's own description from the site:

> GIMP# is an API wrapper around GIMP,
>   written in C#. However, it's not just
>   a wrapper. It also adds a thin layer
>   which adds C# specific features, like
>   iterating through a collection. An
>   example of this is an iteration
>   through the guides of an image.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i am not familiar with C#. i was using opencv for image processing in visual studio and call the native code in android. but now i want to use GEGL libraries. but i cannot compile in visual studio.